Issue with flutter_appauth package: Redirect URI problem during Google sign-in flow
Could you please advise me on the correct usage of the flutter_appauth package?
I am trying to integrate Google Sign-In into my Flutter app and followed the documentation, but I am encountering an issue with the redirect URI.
Here's what I did:
Updated build.gradle with the following code to define the appAuthRedirectScheme:
manifestPlaceholders += [
    'appAuthRedirectScheme':'com.googleusercontent.apps.XXXXXXXX'
]

Modified the AndroidManifest.xml file to include the redirect URI handling:
<activity
    android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
    android:theme="@style/NormalTheme"
    android:exported="true"
    tools:node="replace">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.googleusercontent.apps.XXXXXXXX"
            android:host="auth"
            android:pathPrefix="/callback" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

Flutter code to trigger the Google sign-in flow:
const clientId = 'xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const redirectUri = 'com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxxxx://auth/callback';
const issuer = 'https://accounts.google.com';
const scopes = ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'];

final FlutterAppAuth appAuth = FlutterAppAuth();

Future<void> googleSignIn() async {
  final supabase = SupabaseManager.instance;
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final result = await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
    AuthorizationTokenRequest(
      clientId,
      redirectUri,
      issuer: issuer,
      scopes: scopes,
      serviceConfiguration: AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
          authorizationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth',
          tokenEndpoint: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'
      ),
    ),
  );
}

However, I am getting an error related to the redirect_uri. It seems like the redirect URI is not properly defined.
What I have tried:

Checked the client ID and redirect URI configuration in the Google Cloud Console.
In Google cloud console for Authorized Domain added googleusercontent.com
Followed the flutter_appauth documentation to set up the redirect.

Can anyone advise what the correct way to define the redirect URI is in this case, or if I am missing any configuration?
